# Confusion using "npm ls"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, parse-server

I would be glad if someone could help me to clarify the following.
Though the app works as expected, when I want to see the npm packages installed using this command:

```
npm ls
```

I get the following result:

```
My-Computer:myherokuapp me$ npm ls
parse-server-example@1.4.0 /Users/me/Documents/Heroku/myherokuapp
├── ejs@2.5.7
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY express@~4.11.x
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY kerberos@~0.0.x
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY parse@~1.8.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY parse-server@*

npm ERR! missing: express@~4.11.x, required by parse-server-example@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: kerberos@~0.0.x, required by parse-server-example@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: parse@~1.8.0, required by parse-server-example@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: parse-server@*, required by parse-server-example@1.4.0
My-Computer:myherokuapp me$
```

The output of the command does not seem to report that all is fine, though it works as previously mentioned.

**What am I supposed to think here?**
Are things working but may fail later?
Is something wrong in my configuration?
Is there something I should do?

Comment: Hi, are you running this command on the folder where package.json is located?

Comment: Yes I am. I may have something in some file which should not be there. But I really don't know.